# No enclosing instance .. is accessible

Tags: android, instance

I have this code with error:
[image]

I tried to change this classes to static but only public, abstract and final are permitted.

Comment: Asked and answered many times before - do a search.

Answer (score 0):

for communicating from fragment to activity you need to use fragment callback, directly you can not access, use this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the 'onTextChanged' is overriding an EditText method,  so 'this' is an EditText in the current context. Your parent class name is StartActivity so  you can possibly access to a StartActivity instance using StartActivity.this.

but we can't see here where your KartyListFragment come from. you'll probably have to show more of your code to get better answers.